# copying ASP.NET project files with code to server

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I know you can copy a Website intact to the server and have it run normally (security and compilation time aside).
What about the projects that are in the solution? [whose dll's are copied to the bin when built].  Is there a way to copy the projects' code files to the server as well?

My goal is to be able to debug [by modifying code in the project if needed] directly on the server without having to install an IDE [or keep building on dev machine and copying over dlls].  I can debug/modify the website files, but not the projects.

EDIT:  to clarify, not just debug, but be able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the project files in order to debug files.

You should read about [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx).

---

Update:

What you want to do sounds very dangerous in a production environment. If you want to develop, develop locally.

Regardless - project and solution files are organizational tools in visual studio as well as build files for the MSBuild build tool. If you don't have either visual studio or MSBuild installed on the server, there is little point in having the project and solution files on it.

Why do you need to develop on a production machine?

Comment: added edit to question.  I want to be able to edit the project file code on the server.

Comment: I have two W2K3 Server machines.  One [#1] has the app, and the other [#2] can access that app with no prob (w/ IPv4).  Turned on IPv6 on both machines.  Now, #2 can view the login page of the app, but as I login, it keeps reverting back to the login page.  I'm just trying to narrow down where the disconnect occurs (authentication/IIS/session/code/??).  Dev machine doesn't really matter.  Just need to figure out what on #1 is causing the issue.   I created a temp website with no login control and it works with IPv6, so something with my login/session is up.

Comment: @eych - I fail to see why remote debugging will not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you upload both the DLLs and the PDBs, you should be able to debug successfully without the raw projects on the server.   It can be augmented if you have open the matching project / solutions locally.  There really isn't a requirement to upload solution, project, or raw code files to the server to debug effectively, remotely.  It should be noted that breakig while debugging will hang the app domain on the target application, and as such, should be done with caution in a multiuser environment.